# Ember.js - Action not receiving parameters

Tags: ember.js

I have the following inside my Ember app:

Template:

```
...

<tr id="court-tpl">
    <td class="name">
        <input class="court-name" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3">
    </td>   
    <td class="placement">
        <select class="court-placement">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">Exterior</option>
            <option value="1">Indoor</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="material">
        <select class="court-material">
            <option value="0">Muro</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="1">Cristal</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="single">
        <select class="court-single">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
            <option value="1">Sí</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button {{action "deleteCourtRow" target="view" on="click"}} class="btn btn-small"><i class="icon-remove"></i> Eliminar</button>
    </td>
</tr>

...
```

Corresponding view:

```
var ClubCourtsView = Ember.View.extend({
    ...

    deleteCourtRow: function(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }

    ...
});
```

When the button is clicked, console output is `undefined`. I am trying to get the event.target in order to delete the `<tr>` element, which contains the inline-form.

Any idea of what's happening?

**EDIT**

Controller:

```
    var ClubCourtsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['currentClub'],
    content: null,
    addingCourts: false,

    userCanAddCourts: function() {
        if (this.get('addingCourts') || this.get('hasCustomCourts'))
            return true;

        return false;
    }.observes('addingCourts', 'hasCustomCourts'),

    hasCustomCourts: function() {
        if (this.content.get('customCourts').get('length') > 0)
            return true;

        return false;
    }.property('customCourts'),

    saveCourts: function(data) {
        // Scope reference
        var that = this;

        // Create a record for each row
        $.each(data, function(i) {
                var elId = data[0].elId;

                var r = App.CustomCourt.createRecord();
                r.set('name', data[0].name);
                r.set('single', data[0].single);
                r.set('crystal', data[0].crystal);
                r.set('indoor', data[0].indoor);
                r.set('club', that.content);

                // Remove this row form when model is saved, 
                // as the table is watching for new courts automatically
                r.one('didCreate', function() {
                    $('#' + elId).fadeOut('fast');
                });
        });

        // Send new courts to back-end and update clubmeta: enable custom courts
        this.content.get('clubmeta').set('customCourtsEnabled', true);
        this.store.commit();
    },

    deleteCourt: function(court) {
        court.deleteRecord();
        court.get('transaction').commit();
    }


});

module.exports = ClubCourtsController;
```

The thing is that the table has two kind of rows: the ones showing an existing record (court) and the ones that display a form to create one. There is a button to add more rows dynamically, as a club can have many courts.

Delete button on existing rows deletes `CustomCourt` record from database, which is done in controller's `deleteCourt()`.

**Delete button on form rows, which is where the question is headed to, should only delete the HTML element in the view, that's why I'm using a view function `deleteCourtRow()`. Models for these rows are only created when the save button is pressed (see loop in `saveCourts()`).**

[image: Screenshot]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMj4l.png

Anyway, feel free to recommend another approach as I am a complete newbie using Ember.

Comment: The action helper does not pass the event object to your handler method. Actually this is not the way you should do such logic. I guess your table is backed by an ArrayController? You should pass the model object to your handler so that it can be removed from the underlying ArrayController.

Comment: Show the code of your backing Controller and the handlebars template with iteration over the courts and you we can fix it very fast.

Comment: Read it again and i am not quite sure about the usecase. You are displaying a predefined list of elements. The user may remove elements. And afterwards the remaining elements get saved when a button is pressed?

Comment: Take a look at the screenshot I've just uploaded :)

Comment: Looking at this screenshot i am sure, that this low level DOM Manipulation is not the way you should do it. The list you see there should be backed by an ArrayController and each Row should be represented by an Ember.Object. Those rows do not have to be persistent, when you add a new row. Does this help you or do you need a little snippet to get started?

Comment: Yes, I think I understand. I have to use an `ArrayController` to handle all `CustomCourts` records, instead of doing it manually, right?

Comment: Yes. In your template you are iterating over those records and bind their values to appropriate controls. For instance you use SelectBoxes, use Ember.Select (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html) for this case. Have a look at the valueBinding there. This will automatically set the selected value in your model. And with the help of the action helper you can easily pass the object to a handler in your controller that can remove rows.

Comment: If you have further questions, put up a simple fiddle and we can work it out together :-)