# Ember.js - Binding to another controller's model

Tags: ember.js

In my project, I have the following three models:

- **Club Model**: represents a sports club. It has one `clubMeta` and many `customCourts`.
- **ClubMeta Model**: club related information relevant to the app.
- **CustomCourt Model**: belongs to `club`. A **club** should have **customCourts**  only if `clubMeta.customCourtsEnabled` is `true`.

**Club**

```
var Club = DS.Model.extend({
    ... bunch of properties ...

    clubmeta: DS.belongsTo('App.Clubmeta'),
    customCourts: DS.hasMany('App.CustomCourt')
});

module.exports = Club;
```

**Clubmeta**

```
var Clubmeta = DS.Model.extend({
    ... bunch of properties ...
    customCourtsEnabled: DS.attr('boolean'),

    club: DS.belongsTo('App.Club')
});

module.exports = Clubmeta;
```

**CustomCourt**

```
var CustomCourt = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    glass: DS.attr('boolean'),
    indoor: DS.attr('boolean'),
    single: DS.attr('boolean'),

    club: DS.belongsTo('App.Club')
});

module.exports = CustomCourt;
```

What I need to do is a template where the club (which is the logged in user) can add **customCourts** only if `clubmeta.customCourtsEnabled` is `true`. As I was told in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337602/ember-js-action-not-receiving-parameters), I should be using an `ArrayController` to handle `CustomCourts`.

Everything is ok until this point, the problem comes because `CustomCourtsController` needs to know about **club** and **clubmeta**. I have tried this, with some variations to the binding path:

```
var ClubCourtsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
        needs: ['currentClub'],
        customCourtsEnabledBinding: Ember.Binding.oneWay("App.currentClubController.content.clubmeta.customCourtsEnabled"),
        ...
});
```

**CurrentClubController**

```
var CurrentClubController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        console.log('Retrieving club ' + App.clubId);
        this.set('content', App.Club.find(App.clubId));
    }
});

module.exports = CurrentClubController;
```

But `ClubCourtsController.customCourtsEnabled` always returns undefined. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ClubCourtsController.customCourtsEnabled always returns undefined. What is the right way to do this?

You're on the right track. For starters the right way to do the binding is via the `controllers` property:

```
var ClubCourtsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['currentClub'],
    customCourtsEnabledBinding:     Ember.Binding.oneWay("controllers.currentClub.clubmeta.customCourtsEnabled"),
});
```

Beyond that, it's generally best practice to wire things together in your route's setupController hook instead of a controller init. So even if you've got that binding right, could be other issues causing the customCourtsEnabled property to be undefined. I've posted a working example on jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/ubovil/1/edit

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  clubId: 1
});
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("customCourts", { path: "/" });
});
App.Club = Ember.Object.extend({});
App.Club.reopenClass({
  find: function(id) {
    return App.Club.create({
      id: id, 
      clubmeta: App.ClubMeta.create({
        customCourtsEnabled: true
      })
    });
  }
});
App.ClubMeta = Ember.Object.extend({});
App.CurrentClubController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['currentClub']
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    controller.set('controllers.currentClub.content', App.Club.find(App.clubId));
  }
});

App.CustomCourtsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['currentClub'],
  customCourtsEnabledBinding: Ember.Binding.oneWay("controllers.currentClub.clubmeta.customCourtsEnabled")
});

App.CustomCourtsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    controller.set('content', ['Court a', 'Court b', 'Court c']);
  }
});
```

Comment: Amazing, Mike. So much useful information in your answer, and its working now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the controller via the `controllers` property

```
ClubCourtsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['currentClub'],
  customCourtsEnabledBinding: Ember.Binding.oneWay("controllers.currentClub.clubmeta.customCourtsEnabled"),
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer too Bradley